# why does visual studio jump to the end of html document?

Tags: html, visual-studio

Have just downloaded Visual Studio and am editing an html document. Every time I try to edit a title or a link the editor jumps to the end of the document, while I am typing, so half of the word goes where I want it and the other half ends up at the bottom of the document. As you can imagine it makes for an interesting read lol :) does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

thanks in advance
Linda